how to label parts of an imported Maya model in Unity
I want to import the model you see in the picture to Unity.

Now, my goal is to create a script that will remove part of the model at random. So, in the picture I can place two doors in the red areas. But, the script will decide which door will be brought down, so the other will just stay as part of the wall. How can Unity reference these two specific areas of the model?
